# if focus on a child of parent show parent

Tags: jquery, css, focus, hide, show

I have a drop down that is hidden using left:-9999em; and left:0em; on hover/focus but when I tab through the links within the dropdown the parent that shows the links disappears again.

is there away to make the if child = focus then show parent w/ CSS or jquery

UPDATE....

ok, so I kinda want this jquery

```
$('.sub-nav-wrapper a').focus(function() 
    $(this).parent().css('left','0');
});
```

so that a) it works and b) it hides when focus isn't within it

Comment: Can you show your code snippet?

Comment: Currently trying to get this to work $('.sub-nav-wrapper ul li').focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('shownav');
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(child).click(function() {
    $(this).parent().show();
}
```

I don't know that it's possible in CSS.

Comment: No, selecting the parent is not possible yet with CSS, though CSS4 does promise to bring that as well.